# C26414 issue with using CRecordset

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smart-pointers, crecordset

I have seen a similar discussion here ([C++ Code Analysis in Visual Studio Community 2019 produces warnings C26486 and C26414](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59955747/2287576)) where it refers to using `std::move` but I am not sure if this is what I need to do.

I turned `CRecordset *pRecords = new CRecordSet(&m_dbDatabase)` into smart pointers. Like this:

`auto pRecordset = std::make_unique<CRecordset>(&m_dbDatabase);`

Now I get 8 similar code analysis warnings:

> [C26414](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26414?view=msvc-160): Move, copy, reassign or reset a local smart pointer 'pRecords' (r.5).

I think I understand that fact that this could be turned into a member variable of my `CPTSDatabase` class, that is populated when the database is opened. And then simply use the same pointer.

In an attempt to try and do that I added this to my header file:

`auto m_pRecords = std::unique_ptr<CRecordSet>;`

Then I was going to do this after opening the database:

`m_pRecords = std::make_unique<CRecordSet>(&m_dbDatabase);`

But it does not like how I defined the variable.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your attempt to use `auto` for the class member `m_pRecords`.

First, you can't use `auto` for (non-static) class member variables. I can't find an *explicit* rule for this in [this C++17 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), but the very first part of the **[dcl.spec.auto]** section does, indirectly, cover it (emphasis mine):

> ##### 10.1.7.4 The `auto` specifier       [dcl.spec.auto]
>
> <sup>1</sup>     The `auto`
> and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* are used to designate a
> placeholder type ***that will be replaced later by deduction from an
> initializer***. …

So, when defining a class, that *later* deduction is not appropriate, as the class isn't fully defined from the information you provide.

---

And second, even outside a class definition, the `auto m_pRecords = std::unique_ptr<CRecordset>;` expression is invalid syntax. The `auto` keyword allows a variable's type to be deduced from the value of the **expression** given as its initialisation (the right-hand operator of the `=`) – and a type name is *not* an expression.

---

So, as a solution, you should declare the smart-pointer member of your class like this:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<CRecordset> m_pRecords;
```

Comment: Note: There does seem to be a *slightly* more explicit clause in an earlier C++ Standard, as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199974/10871073).

Comment: Thanks for your help is clearing up this issue and for the links to extra info.